# How to get the value of a python dictionary by providing variable key

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have a python dictionary such as.....document = {
"brand": "Ford",
"model": "Mustang",
"year": 1964
}
now I want to get the value of any key by providing a variable as key.
like answer = document[x]; where x can be "brand", "model", or "year".
How this is possible?

Comment: You already have the solution `answer = document[x]`. The only thing you could change is use `answer = document.get(x, None)` or something to handle looking up from the dictionary if the key may not be present.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getValueFromDict(key, dict):
    '''
    Returns the value of the given key, if key doesn't exist in dictionary the 
    function will throw a KeyError.
    key: string
    dict: dictionary    
    return: string
    '''

    return dict[key]
```

Comment: should explain your answer instead of dumping code

Comment: Theres honestly not much to explain, it literally 2 lines of code. One declaring the function that intakes 2 parameters which were both described in the doc string, and the other simply returning the value of the dictionary at the given input parameter. I think the doc string explained that.......